# .net MVC 3 multiple columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i want to display a list in more columns with 5 items/column

my code now doesn't work as expected:

```
@{
    var c=0;
 }

<div >


@foreach (var item in Model) {
     c += 1;
    @Html.ActionLink(item.Judet , "Browse", new { judet = item.Judet }) <br />

     if (c == 5){
         Response.Write("</div><div style='border: 1px solid red;'>");
         c = 0;
     }

}

 </div>
```

When i run the code i get this:
[image]

Comment: What do you get when running this code, add the output to understand more the issue

Comment: @IMAnis_tn i get all the red divs on top empty and in the content the full list requested .

Comment: Well i wouldn't use Response.Write in MVC

Comment: @rudeovski ze bear I new to MVC i would love another suggestion on how is better to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the code to

```
 if (c == 5){
     @:</div><div style='border: 1px solid red;'>
     c = 0;
 }
```

Comment: see my edited post for the question. I do not know what your model is, so I dont know what you are trying to display

Comment: It is @model IEnumerable<hotelsinbrasov.Judete>

Comment: Then maybe item.Judet is empty

Comment: not empty look at the picture attached it returns the item.Judet correctly

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to apply a class/style to your divs for columns. Hence the long list, instead of columns.

And you dont need `Response.Write`, you  can just put the html in there without it.

For the list, you might want to use UL/LI instead.

e.g.

```
<ul class="columnstyle">
@foreach (var item in Model.SomethingList) {
     c += 1;
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Judet , "Browse", new { judet = item.Judet })</li>

     if (c == 5){
         @:</ul><ul style='border: 1px solid red;'>
         c = 0;
     }
}
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you , this working too without the SomethingList property